# How to use multiple whereBetween to sum two different record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I need to compare and sum data from two different date.

Assuming i have 4 input dates

```
startdate = "2020-11-01",
enddate = "2020-11-30",
compare_startdate = "2020-12-01",
compare_enddate = "2020-12-31",
```

Currently, my query only able to get one whereBetween date data as below

Current Code

```
$raw_data = ChartOfAccount::with(array(
    'journal' => function($query) use ($init)
    {
            $query->selectRaw('*,
            sum(item_journals.debit) as total_debit,
            sum(item_journals.credit) as total_credit,
            sum(item_journals.debit) - sum(item_journals.credit) as net_movement');
            $query->groupBy('chart_of_account_id');
            $query->where('item_journals.deleted_at', null);
            $query->whereBetween('date', array($init['startdate'], $init['enddate']));                
    }
    ))
    ->get();
```

Current result from `startdate` and `enddate`

```
"total_debit" => "0.00"
"total_credit" => "200.00"
"net_movement" => "-200.00"
```

Example another result from `compare_startdate` and `compare_enddate`

```
 "total_debit" => "0.00"
 "total_credit" => "50.00"
 "net_movement" => "-50.00"
```

How to query another result from `compare_startdate` to `compare_enddate` in order to sum result of `startdate` and `enddate`?

Expected result

```
"total_debit" => "0.00"
"total_credit" => "150.00"
"net_movement" => "-150.00"
```

I did try something like this in query but result is incorrect

```
$query->whereBetween('date', array($init['startdate'], $init['enddate']));                
$query->whereBetween('date', array($init['compare_startdate'], $init['compare_enddate']));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Friend You Can Use orWhereBetween in advance where clause as below,

```
DB::table('tbl')
  ->Where(function ($query) use ($startdate,$enddate,$compare_startdate,$compare_enddate) {
      $query->whereBetween('date', [$startdate, $enddate]);
      $query->orWhereBetween('date', [$compare_startdate, $compare_enddate] );
})->get();
```